# UITableview not refreshing on viewWillAppear or performSelectorOnMainThread with 1 row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

So, I am trying to do something that I think is fairly simple, yet this is causing me no end of pain.

Essentially I have a ViewController, and from here you can open another ViewController which again you can load another ViewController from. In this last ViewController you can select a row which will add some data to NSUserdefaults (Using a class that I built to handle this data)

This all works fine, and the data is added. Now when I go back to my first ViewController whence the journey began, using viewWillAppear I ask it to get the data from NSUserdefaults and then refresh the data in a table that is in this view.

```
    let jsonData = JSON(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("set")!)
    self.tracks = jsonData.arrayObject!
    print(self.tracks)
    self.tblSongs.reloadData()
```

Now this never seems to work when there is just 1 row in the array, however if there is more than 1 row, then everything works fine and the table is visible with the required amount of data.

The Print does indeed show the data that is stored, and I can see the single row that is stored but is not showing up in the table.

Has anyone had anything similar or any idea what I can do to solve this?

I have tried using a delegate, NSNotificationCenter, and performing spells but everything returns the same result.

Many thanks in advance for your help

*Disclaimer I am new to native iOS and Swift being a JS Developer and previously using Titanium

EDIT: I have logged numberOfRowsInSection and this returns 1 as expected, but cellForRowAtIndexPath does not get fired

EDIT 2: Here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath code, this isn't fired even though there is 1 item in the array and numberOfRowsInSection says 1. This does work fine if you re-launch the app

EDIT 3: Here is the entire Class

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Main: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var viewNoTracks: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var viewTracksNoSet: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var btnPlay: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var tblSongs: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var lblStatus: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var btnSubmitSet: UIButton!

var tracks = []

let setMgr = SetManager()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let bgColor: UIColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    self.btnSubmitSet.layer.borderColor = bgColor.CGColor
    self.btnSubmitSet.layer.borderWidth = 1

    self.tblSongs.delegate = self
    self.tblSongs.dataSource = self

    if self.setMgr.getCurrentSetCount() > 0 {
        self.viewTracksNoSet.hidden = false
        self.viewNoTracks.hidden = true
        self.updateData()
    } else {
        self.viewTracksNoSet.hidden = true
        self.viewNoTracks.hidden = false
    }
    self.checkSetStatus()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        if self.setMgr.getCurrentSetCount() > 0 {
            self.viewTracksNoSet.hidden = false
            self.viewNoTracks.hidden = true
            self.updateData()
        } else {
            self.viewTracksNoSet.hidden = true
            self.viewNoTracks.hidden = false
        }
        self.checkSetStatus()
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func openPlay(sender: AnyObject){
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segueChoonSelector", sender: nil)
}

@IBAction func unwindToMain(segue: UIStoryboardSegue){

}

@IBAction func submitSet(sender: AnyObject){

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellMainSong", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CellMainSong

    let row = self.tracks[indexPath.row]

    var artist = row["artist"] as! String
    artist = artist.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&amp;", withString: "&", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    var song = row["song"] as! String
    song = song.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&amp;", withString: "&", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    var genre = row["genre"] as! String
    genre = genre.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&amp;", withString: "&", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)

    print(artist)

    cell.lblDetails.text = artist + " - " + song + " - " + genre

    return cell

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.tracks.count
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
        let row = self.tracks[indexPath.row]
        let tid = row["tid"] as! String
        self.setMgr.removeFromSet(tid)
        self.updateData()
    }
}

func UITableView_Auto_Height()
{
    if(self.tblSongs.contentSize.height < self.tblSongs.frame.height){
        var frame: CGRect = self.tblSongs.frame;
        frame.size.height = self.tblSongs.contentSize.height;
        self.tblSongs.frame = frame;
    }
}

func setSetLabelOrButton(){
    if self.setMgr.getCurrentSetCount() < 3 {

        let currCountInt: Int = self.setMgr.getCurrentSetCount()

        let tracksLeft = 3 - currCountInt

        let currentCount = String(tracksLeft)
        self.btnSubmitSet.hidden = true
        self.lblStatus.hidden = false

        if currentCount == "1" {
            self.viewTracksNoSet.hidden = false
            self.viewNoTracks.hidden = true
            self.lblStatus.text = "Hey DJ, you are " + currentCount + " track away from rocking the dancefloor"
        } else if currentCount == "3" {
            self.viewTracksNoSet.hidden = true
            self.viewNoTracks.hidden = false
        } else {
            self.lblStatus.text = "Hey DJ, you are " + currentCount + " tracks away from rocking the dancefloor"
        }


    } else if self.setMgr.getCurrentSetCount() == 3 {
        self.lblStatus.hidden = true
        self.btnSubmitSet.hidden = false
    }
}

func updateData(){
    let jsonData = JSON(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("set")!)
    self.tracks = jsonData.arrayObject!
    print(self.tracks)
    self.tblSongs.reloadData()
    self.performSelectorOnMainThread(Selector("updateTableData"), withObject: self.tblSongs, waitUntilDone: false)
    self.setSetLabelOrButton()
    self.UITableView_Auto_Height()
}

func updateTableData(){
    self.tblSongs.reloadData()
}


func checkSetStatus(){
    let setStatus = SetStatus()
    setStatus.getSetStatus { (resp) -> Void in
        //print(resp)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Interesting issue, also sounds like a BUG from the description above...
I would try to solve this by adding invisible row in tableView... which just has no UI (return height for row (if last row 0.0)). Hope it will help to work this round, also you can post a bug report to Apple

Comment: I would also try to add a slight delay in viewWillAppear before you are reloading the data... (Delay that won't block the thread of course).

Comment: I was wondering about whether it might be a BUG, but wanted to double check before making a fool of myself. I'll give that a go though and see if it works.

Comment: Well I don't know to be honest maybe it is not a bug -> but sound like from what you have described. 
Also if Delaying will work... it is probably not a bug ;-)

Comment: I have tried a dispatch method on the main thread and it still had the same result, I really don't like the idea of a timer, but I'll try it

Comment: No don't do that, dispatch was enough to check it.
try to add a dummy cell instead of wasting a time on a timer.

Comment: Can you post your tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) code please?

Comment: @fragilecat I have added that above

Comment: So have you set a breakpoint in this method when you only have one song?  You can also use print statements too. Is the data present? We want to work out if it a UI issue or a data issue.

Comment: You might want to rule out that it not your custom UITableView class CellSongs. I would revert to a UITAbleViewCell and see if it works then.

Comment: @fragilecat Yep, tried that, the breakpoint is fired when the app is loaded the first time and there is 1 row. However if I delete that row (and delete from the array) and then add a new item when I go back to the main view the breakpoint isn't fired (So cellForRowAtIndexPath doesn't get called). If I add a second item and go back, the breakpoint is triggered.

Comment: @fragilecat Good point on the CustomCell, I do re-use that in a different Tableview elsewhere in the app, I'll try creating a different one and see if that sorts it, as actually the 2 views that I am trying this out on do use the same custom cell at the moment. (Although I thought that should be ok!)

Comment: So you are calling reloadData()  when?

Comment: Nope that didn't work either. Using a different custom cell had the same effect. I call reloadData in viewWillAppear

Comment: So I would now start looking at your data structure as it does not appear to be a UI issue.

Comment: I don't understand what I can look at any differently though, when I print out the data I can see it in the console. And the numberOfRowsInSection gets the count of this data, which again is correct. Also when there is more than 1 result it works fine. So I guess I don't really know where to start with it

Comment: Try changing the cell background color when you have only one song, that way you can see if the method is being called. Check that you are setting the correct number of cells in' tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)'

Comment: Can you post the whole view controller  class and a sample of your json object.

Comment: Also review what is in your custom cell's prepareForReuse() method.

Comment: Have added the whole class and here is a parsed version of the data,         {
        artist = "Ray Charles";
        genre = "60 soul";
        song = "Hit the Road Jack";
        tid = 5395a0f81fc8975b05d5afe1;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get the reason Bt just log what value does "numberOfSections" in tableview returns. It may not be the reason but just try

Comment: numberOfSections says 1 as expected :/

Answer (score 0):

I found out the issue. Turns out that self.UITableView_Auto_Height() was being called before the data had been loaded, causing the table to render at 0 height. Although interestingly it still wasn't firing the cellForRowAtIndex, so perhaps an issue with the lifecycle in this case